# RegEX JS pattern: 0.000 - 1.600

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx Pattern which is limited from 0.000 - 1.600

This is what i have got so far:

```
^(?:0(?:\.0)?|0?\.[0-9]{1,3}|1(?:\.0{1,3})?|1?\.[0-6]{1,3})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/F5ZIPoSzmK6Y3dzR)

**Problem:**

This pattern also allows values up to 1.666
But it should only allow values up to **1.600.**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not remove the dot and test it is between 0 and 1600 and that the string is 5 chars long? OR starts with a "1." and a number from 0 to 600

Comment: regExp is too difficult, work with numbers!

Comment: updated my ans, i hope new one works

Comment: so many answers being written, deleted and downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YQtmRK7zj3RUtUya) regular expression matches all float numbers with at most four digits from `0.000` to `1.600`. It also matches `0` and `1`:

```
^(?:1(?:\.(?:[0-5]\d{0,2}|60{0,2})|)|0(?:\.\d{1,3})?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

(Apart from that, why not use numbers?)

Comment: It doesn't however accept values like ".5" which probably should be correct. But it can be easily fixed: `^(?:0|0?(?:\.\d{1,3})|1(?:\.(?:[0-5]\d{0,2}|60{0,2}))?)$`

Comment: This is what i wanted, thank you. I do not want the user to enter .6 or anything like that. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change the last alternation

```
1?\.[0-6]{1,3}
```

becomes

```
1?\.[0-5]\d{0,2}|1?\.60?0?
```

Comment: matched 1.6 from 1.666

Comment: @NabeelKhan: Certainly not, because of the `$` sign at the end of the original regex

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without RegExp, thay are to `havy` for such tasks.

Try another method:

```
var test = ['0.000', '1.021', '1.600', '1.666'],
    value;

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
 value = (+test[i] * 1000).toFixed(0); // +test[i] -> convert to number

 if (value < 0 || value > 1600) {
    console.log('Bad value is: ' + test[i]); // will print 1.666
 }
}
```

real example https://jsfiddle.net/xrwupphj/

Answer (score -1):

This should work

## Edited

```
0\.\d{3}|1\.(?:[0-5]\d{2}|600)
```

Here's the link https://www.debuggex.com/r/DzUBZn_gjKiChOjJ

Comment: This doesn't match `0.999`.

Comment: Now it doesn't match `0` or `1.2`, but OP's does.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty easy though, use this regex:

```
((?:0\.\d{3}|1\.[0|1|2|3|4|5]\d{2}|1\.600))
```

Tested here:

https://regex101.com/r/rS6eJ8/3

Comment: This doesn't match `0.999`.

Comment: This will match `|.|12`

Comment: Now it matches `1.|12` but not `0` or `0.5` that isn't what OP want.

Comment: how r u matching? it does match 0.000 and 0.500 :) that's exactly how op wanted